# The system cannot find the file specified while running the emulator in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Whenever i try to run emulator it gives me error, when I checked my idea.log file then it displaying this error. (I recently installed android studio)

**This is the error:**

```
INFO - Emulator: Small Phone API 34 - [10804:11320:20240309,181705.418:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes
```

---

```
 C:\Users\mu974\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.19.db\attachments\55909d50-d226-4576-81f9-d13686f2888e: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Looks to me more like an error while the emulator crashed, therefore it is an error while processing an error. The main problem is. To me it seems like the emulator crash is your problem, not this error message.